# Does WPF/Xaml have something like Flex/MXML's ViewStack

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

ViewStack in Flex/MXML is a container/panel control that holds multiple children but only makes one visible at a time, useful for implementing your own tab-style controls.  Does WPF/Xaml have a class that works the same as this?  I know it has its own dedicated tab control (what I'm trying to do isn't really a tab control, so not useful) and StackPanel, which isn't the same.

Answer (score 2):

A) Use a grid, and toggle the Visibility property (multiple UIElements can be in one cell in a grid
B) Use a tab control, but restyle it as you see fit
C) Swap out the actual Content property in a ContentPresenter -- e.g. shove the instance of the UI you want into it, when you want it in it.

Comment: D) Write a custom control in about 2 mintues to switch between a collection of child content.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, templating any ItemsControl is the easiest way if you don't want to write a custom control.

E.g. have some inner panel's visibility in item's container bound to the IsSelected property's value (through BooleanToVisibilityConverter).